# The difference between $* and $@

Tags: bash, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What the difference between “$@” and “$*” in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008695/what-the-difference-between-and-in-bash)

For years and on dozens of occasions, I have hesitated between the use of `$*` and `$@` in shell scripts.  Having read the applicable section of Bash's manpage over and over again, having tried both `$*` and `$@`, I more or less completely fail to understand the practical difference of application between the two variables.  Can you enlighten me, please?

I have been using `$*` recently, but don't ask me why.  I don't know why, because I don't know why `$@` even exists, except as an almost exact synonym for `$*`.

Is there any practical difference?

(I personally tend to use Bash, but remain agnostic regarding the choice of shell.  My question is not specific to Bash as far as I know.)

Comment: Searching for [$* $@](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%24%40+%24*) on SymbolHound finds a number of duplicates. Handy tool, that.

Comment: (Also, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307672/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-unix, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761723/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-shell-scripts, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491115/what-is-the-internal-processing-of-and.)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan:  Confirmed on all points.  SymbolHound does look handy.  I hadn't known about it.  Next time, I will search there first.  Should I take some action to merge my question with the one you suggest?

Comment: It certainly is hard finding things when Stack OVerflow's search engine doesn't cope with symbols. You decide what to do about this question.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: I have voted to close my own question.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Unquoted, there is no difference -- they're expanded to all the arguments and they're split accordingly.  The difference comes when quoting. `"$@"` expands to properly quoted arguments and `"$*"` makes all arguments into a single argument. Take this for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

function print_args_at {
    printf "%s\n" "$@"
}

function print_args_star {
    printf "%s\n" "$*"
}

print_args_at "one" "two three" "four"
print_args_star "one" "two three" "four"
```

Then:

```
$ ./printf.sh 

one
two three
four

one two three four
```

Answer (score 8):

Consider:

```
foo() { mv "$@"; } 
bar() { mv "$*"; }
foo a b
bar a b
```

The call to foo will attempt to mv file a to b.  The call to bar will fail since it calls mv with only one argument.

Comment: Thank you.  Are *$@* and *$\** then identical if used without quote marks?

Comment: Without quotes, $@ and $* are identical.

Comment: Also, on some broken shells `"$@"` expands to an empty argument `""` if there are no positional parameters, rather than correctly expanding to nothing. So this trick has to be used: `${@+"$@"}` (if `$@` is nonblank, substitute `"$@"` else nothing) . If you ever see that, you will know why.

Comment: I always used `${1+"$@"}`, which works the same as `${@+"$@"}`.  Was glad to dump the silly construct... :-)

Answer (score 6):

Note also that `"$@"` is magic *only* when there's nothing else in the quotes. These are identical:

```
set -- a "b c" d
some_func "foo $*"  
some_func "foo $@"
```

In both cases, some_func receives one argument.